# How to make the program wait until a timer thread is finished before it continues?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a small program to learn java, I wanted to print something, wait a few seconds (shown by printing . . .) then continue the program. I did this by using `Timer` and `TimerTask`. I want to know how to make the execution of the program wait until my timer thread is over.

I tried adding `timer.wait()` in some places but it doesn't work.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("text1");
        clock currentClock = new clock();
        currentClock.run();
        // i want the program to stop until this is over, adding currentClock.wait(); doesnt work
        System.out.println("text2");
    }
}

class clockHelper extends TimerTask
{ // printing class, called by clock class

    int actual = 0;

    public void run()
    {
        if (actual < 3)
        {
            System.out.println(".");
            actual++;
        } else
        {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}

class clock
{ // called by main class
    public static void run()
    {

        Timer watch = new Timer();
        TimerTask timer2 = new clockHelper();
        watch.schedule(timer2, 1000, 500);
        // adding watch.wait(); doesn't work, i can also stop it here and it should work fine
    }
}
```

This is the error I get: `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException`

The result that I want is to print this:
"text" . . . "text2"

If I remove the `wait` (which leads to error) instead it prints:
"text1" "text2" . . .

Thanks in advance for any info.

Comment: in which line the error occurs please ?

Comment: Would Thread.sleep do what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `java.util.Timer`? If all you want to do is launch a new `Thread` and then wait in the launching thread for the launched thread to complete, there a several ways to achieve that. So do you have to use `Timer`, or will a different approach be acceptable? For a start, consider method [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--). Another option would be method [submit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: Also, I think you are confused with regard to the use and purpose of method [wait()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--). I suggest reading the _Concurrency_ lesson in _Oracle_'s _Java Tutorial_. Method `wait()` is described in the Web page entitled [Guarded Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: I don't have to use timer, I just looked how to "do a timer" and most of the results recommended the timer library. and yea after reading a bit i was wrong at what wait() does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do something like that:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("text1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            System.out.print(".");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("text2");
    }
}
```